# Is it correct to say "lower the possibility"?

Tags: meaning

I searched on the internet, found sentences like lowering the risk, but I don't know if it's correct to say "lower the possibility" or I should say "reduce the possibility."

Comment: "Reduced the possibility" is probably more idiomatic, but "lower the possibility" is perfectly correct.

Comment: @HotLicks Please make it an answer to this question~

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence. The usage can be quite idiomatic. We need more context to judge the acceptability. It may be that *probability* should replace *possibility*.

Comment: reduce* the possibility.

Comment: @PhilSweet I reckon Hot Licks (quite a name, isn't it?) is correct. Possibility can be 'measured' in terms of risk management. It could be *Lower the effect. There is a high possibility to have lower effect. Oh well, I guess reduce effect is also perfectly correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Reduced the possibility" is probably more idiomatic, but "lower the possibility" is perfectly correct.

As Karma suggests, "possibility" can, in theory, be quantified, and either "reducing" or "lowering" the quantity would mean creating circumstances where the activity being characterized is less likely to occur.